# AJAX upload images from array to process with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I have a simple form so you can upload images. I store the uploaded images' properties in a array but I want to post this array to a PHP file using ajax. If I try to get the uploaded image: `$_FILES['image1']`, it returns an empty array. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

PS: It is important to store the images' properties in a array and pass it to a FormData.

```js
var foo = []; var input = document.getElementById('input');
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  foo.push(input.files[0]);
});
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(foo);
});

document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var fd = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    fd.append('image'+i, foo[i]);
  }

  $.ajax({ 
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/php.file",
    data: fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
    error: function (err) { console.log(err); }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="check">CHECK</button>
<button id="upload">UPLOAD</button>
<br><br>
<input type="file" id="input" placeholder="UPLOAD IMAGE">
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
    array_push($arr, $_FILES);
    die(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you just `print_r( $_FILES );` without trying to encode JSON ..

Comment: Is this your exact code? If so then your `fd` variable is set before any images (or form data) is ready. More specifically, you loop through the `foo` array, which will have 0 items at the time that loop is executed.

Comment: @Zak It returns an empty array: `Array() 1`

Comment: @EssXTee No, sorry, I have edited the code. First, you upload the images, then click on the `ADD` button to add the images to the `foo` array, then click on the `UPLOAD` button to send the ajax request

Comment: array_push needs 2 params (?)

Comment: If you don't add anything to `$arr` it's gonna be empty.

Comment: @James I have fixed it, but nothing changed. Is it even possible to get the `$_FILES` from an array?

Comment: `PS: It is important to store the images' properties in a array and pass it to a FormData.` This might not be possible.  Do you know for sure that it is?  Does it upload successfully if you don't do this and build formdata from the input element?

Comment: `enctype: "multipart/form-data"` - remove that. You are most likely overwriting the _proper_ Content-Type header, that FormData automatically created, which also contains the _boundary_ value, which is necessary to be able to _parse_ a multipart request on the receiving end.

Answer (score -1):

Or you need to check php.ini and check if the size of all the images you add exceeds "upload_max_filesize"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I executed the code  with two files. It seems that you can print the files successfully with the following code (PHP file)

```
    print_r($_FILES['image0']);
    print_r($_FILES['image1']);
```

I used jquery 3.5.1, for the ajax call.

I hope it helps.